# Android ScrollView is not automatically scrolling

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am probably missing something very simple here but I can't for the life of me see it.

I am trying to get the ScrollView working in an Android application. While the layout looks good, the Text / image will not scroll automatically

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ScrollView 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".NasaDailyImage" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_image_title" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_image_date" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
            android:contentDescription="@string/test_image_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_image_description" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <Button android:text="@string/refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#ff8D8D8D"
            android:onClick="refreshScreen"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Give some height to scrollview like 100dp. Add some more textviews. It will work

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this too but it has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    **android:layout_height="fill_parent"**
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp" />
```

just fill_parent to your scroll view height that it dude

Comment: ooooo not close this like  "/>" just use instance of "/>" to ">" and close this after all your scroll view end

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the tag is already set to ">" as per my code above.

Comment: just remove this line "android:layout_weight="1" " from scroll view and run

Comment: No luck I'm afraid - still not scrolling.

Comment: heyy dude if all data is confrt on screen then y it will scroll, it scroll until or unless it will be larger then display screen